# How do I reset a user password in hudson?

Tags: hudson

I've lost the admin user password on hudson (actually it just randomly stopped working), I can get back in by disabling security (editing ~/.hudson/config.xml) then I can configure hudson, but I can't find any options to add new users or change/reset user passwords - maybe these options don't appear when security is disabled? I was using the matrix-based security. How can I add a new user or reset the password for existing ones?

Comment: http://polygoncell.blogspot.com/2009/02/hudson-forget-password-reset-password.html

Comment: Fixed. Thanks to all that replied. If you have this problem and have to manually edit config.xml to disable security temporarily, be sure to re-apply the "Hudson's own user database" in the "Security Realm" section when you re-enable security, as well as setting up the privileges matrix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](http://polygoncell.blogspot.com/2009/02/hudson-forget-password-reset-password.html) is an article outlining how that is achieved.

> The first one: edit the authorization setting in the config.xml file
>   if you have defined more users in your Hudson and you at least one
>   user’s password. For example, your user name called peter and you know
>   the password of the user jack, in this case, just open the
>   `%HUDSON_HOME%/config.xml` and find the line:
>
> ```
> <permission>Hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:peter</permission>
> ```
>
> And add a new line below:
>
> ```
> <permission>Hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:jack</permission>
> ```
>
> Save your change and restart your Hudson server, then you can login as
>   jack and change your own password. After then login using your own
>   account and go to `http://your/hudson/configure` and change jack back
>   to his normal authorization setting.
>
> The other way ist just editing your own `config.xml`, in this case, open
>   `%HUDSON_HOME%/your/config.xml` and find the line:
>
> ```
> <password>………</password>
> ```
>
> The text between the password tag is encoded, so you can’t just enter
>   your password as plain text here. The easy way for you now is just
>   remove all the text between that tag, in another word, just let the
>   password empty.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem I was having is that even when I enabled admin privileges for Anonymous, I couldn't set/reset passwords - I eventually found that the "Security Realm" had been unset from hudson's own database to nothing at all, so even with security enabled and matrix permissions set up correctly, there were no password options anywhere to set/reset/etc. - This is a problem with temporarily disabling security manually from the config.xml - it silently breaks a load of other settings.

Comment: surprised this answer got 5 upvotes - special characters in the text meant that some of the most important parts were invisible. please review your answers carefully before submitting, especially when copy/pasting from external sources

Comment: +1...although this worked I am surprised there isn't an easier way to do this. Well, time to get the old Java book out and create a plugin to make it a seamless process!

Comment: Adding the Administer permission for a user with a known password also works in Jenkins (v1.572).  Trying to modify config.xml, however, was unsuccessful because the <password> field is replaced by <passwordHash>, and leaving it blank did not permit logging in.

Answer (score 4):

In Hudson 3.0, security is defined in a separate file, hudson-security.xml.  Same directory though.

Just edit the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` entry and specify false.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the jenkins files, edit the config.xml.

/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml

Change

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

And comment to

```
<authorizationStrategy/>
```

Ref:
http://it.i88.ca/2013/04/reset-password-of-jenkins.html

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org), but this should be similar in Hudson. You need to be logged in as a user with administrative permissions, so configuring Hudson to use security is essential. Look for a 'Manage Users' link in the 'Manage Hudson' page (the main configuration page linked from the main page). The 'Manage Users' page should give you a list of users that have been configured for use with Hudson and you should be able to add/edit/delete users from here.

Read [this](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Securing+Hudson) article for more information on configuring security in Hudson.